# Pyinstaller EXE will only run from CMD, clicking on the EXE doesn't work

Tags: python, tkinter, exe, pyinstaller, packaging

I have made a simple python program for a friend of mine that makes use of `tkinter` and `SMTPlib`.
I used `pyinstaller` to make an .exe for the program, but when I double click the .exe my CMD terminal will flash on the screen for a split second than disappear. When I drag that same .exe to my CMD terminal and press enter, the program runs with no issues, every feature of the program works.

I am attaching my .spec file that `pyinstaller` created, I have not modified it at all. I really feel like it should work, given that it 100% works if I call it from the CMD, only issues are when I double-click on the .exe. Extremely frustrating.

I have seen this same issue posted online several times, and there is no solution I have seen that has helped me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Following the advice below I was able to get the program to run. I had to change the .spec file, specifically the `datas` field in order to get it to work. However I am now having a problem where the .txt files will load, but upon editing them the edits are not saved as they should be. The edits were all being saved BEFORE I fixed the original issue, when I was only able to run the program from the CMD. I am posting the entire script below:

EDIT II: I had not put the files into 'w' mode, and this is why I wasn't getting any output to the text files. All is working now!

My spec file:

```
block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['test.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\wiley\\PycharmProjects\\EmailBot\\email_bot2'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('students1.txt', '.'),('students2.txt','.')],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='test',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=False )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='test')
```

my main.py file:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import re
import email_data
import smtplib
import os

__location__ = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.dirname(__file__)))

student_view = None
email_string = ''


def display_email():
    def save_and_close():
        preview_window.destroy()

    preview_window = Toplevel()
    preview_window.title("Preview")
    preview_window.geometry('-680+300')
    preview_window.grab_set()
    preview_window.lift(root)

    preview_frame = ttk.Frame(preview_window, padding=10)
    preview = Text(preview_frame)
    close_button = Button(preview_frame, text='Close', command=save_and_close)

    preview_frame.grid()
    preview.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='NSEW')
    close_button.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='NSEW')

    preview.insert(END, email_string)


def format_email():
    global email_string
    email_string = email_data.email_string_raw.format(this_lab_name=t1.get(), zoom_date_time=t2.get(),
                                                      zoom_link=t3.get(),
                                                      zoom_ID=t4.get(),
                                                      zoom_passcode=t5.get(), this_lab_supplemental=t6.get(),
                                                      this_lab_consisting=t7.get(),
                                                      this_lab_due=t8.get(), file_name_tag=t9.get(),
                                                      last_lab_reminder=t10.get(),
                                                      last_lab_due=t11.get(),
                                                      last_lab_supplemental=t12.get(), last_file_name_tag=t13.get())
    view_email_button['state'] = 'normal'
    send_button['state'] = 'normal'


def send_email():
    global p, z, email_string, emails1, emails2

    def send_email_final():
        smtp_obj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com', port=587)
        smtp_obj.starttls()
        email = email_input.get()
        password = email_pass_input.get()
        smtp_obj.login(email, password)

        from_address = email_input.get()

        msg = "Subject: CHML101: Weekly Instructional Email" + '\n\n' + email_string
        to_address_list = []
        if p.get() == 1:
            data = open(os.path.join(__location__, 'students1.txt'))
            emails = data.read()
            to_address_list = emails.split('\n')
            print(to_address_list.__str__())
        elif p.get() == 2:
            data = open(os.path.join(__location__, 'students2.txt'))
            emails = data.read()
            to_address_list = emails.split('\n')
            print(to_address_list.__str__())

        print(msg)
        smtp_obj.sendmail(from_address, to_address_list, msg)

    def confirm_normal():
        confirm_check['state'] = 'normal'

    def send_normal():
        if z.get() == 1:
            send_email_button['state'] = 'normal'
        else:
            send_email_button['state'] = 'disabled'

    send_email_window = Toplevel()
    send_email_window.title("Send Email")
    send_email_window.geometry('400x175-680+300')
    send_email_window.grab_set()
    send_email_window.lift(root)

    send_frame = ttk.Frame(send_email_window)
    email_label = Label(send_frame, text='Enter your email address:')
    pass_label = Label(send_frame, text='Enter your email password:')
    email_input = Entry(send_frame)
    email_pass_input = Entry(send_frame, show='*')
    class_label1 = Label(send_frame, text='Email class 1:')
    class_label2 = Label(send_frame, text='Email class 2:')
    class_radio1 = Radiobutton(send_frame, var=p, value=1, command=confirm_normal)
    class_radio2 = Radiobutton(send_frame, var=p, value=2, command=confirm_normal)
    confirm_label = Label(send_frame, text='Confirm selection:')
    confirm_check = Checkbutton(send_frame, state='disabled', variable=z, command=send_normal)
    send_email_button = Button(send_frame, text='Send Email', state='disabled', command=send_email_final)

    send_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='NSEW')
    email_label.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2)
    pass_label.grid(column=2, row=0, columnspan=2)
    email_input.grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=2)
    email_pass_input.grid(column=2, row=1, columnspan=2)
    class_label1.grid(column=0, row=2)
    class_label2.grid(column=2, row=2)
    class_radio1.grid(column=1, row=2)
    class_radio2.grid(column=3, row=2)
    confirm_label.grid(column=1, row=3)
    confirm_check.grid(column=2, row=3)
    send_email_button.grid(columnspan=2, column=1, row=4)


def class_list_view():
    global emails1, emails2, v, student_view

    def update_txt():
        items = student_view.get(0, 'end')
        if v.get() == 2:
            data1 = open(os.path.join(__location__, 'students2.txt'), mode='w')
            first = True
            for item in items:
                if first:
                    data1.write(item)
                    first = False
                else:
                    data1.write('\n' + item)
            data1.close()
        if v.get() == 1:
            data1 = open(os.path.join(__location__, 'students1.txt'), mode='w')
            first = True
            for item in items:
                if first:
                    data1.write(item)
                    first = False
                else:
                    data1.write('\n' + item)
            data1.close()

    def check_email():
        email = add_student_entry.get()
        if re.match(r'\w+@\w+.\w+', email) is not None:
            add_student()
            add_student_label['text'] = 'Add new student Email:'
            update_txt()
        else:
            add_student_label['text'] = 'EMAIL FORMAT INVALID'

    def delete_student():
        student_view.delete('active')
        update_txt()

    def add_student():
        if v.get() == 2:
            emails2_curr = emails2.get()
            emails2_curr = list(emails2_curr)
            emails2_curr.append(add_student_entry.get())
            emails2.set(emails2_curr)
            add_student_entry.delete(0, 'end')
        if v.get() == 1:
            emails1_curr = emails1.get()
            emails1_curr = list(emails1_curr)
            emails1_curr.append(add_student_entry.get())
            emails1.set(emails1_curr)
            add_student_entry.delete(0, 'end')

    def assign_class():
        if v.get() == 2:
            student_view['listvariable'] = emails2
        elif v.get() == 1:
            student_view['listvariable'] = emails1

    class_list = Toplevel()
    class_list.title("View/Edit Class Lists")
    class_list.geometry('400x200-680+300')
    class_list.grab_set()
    class_list.lift(root)

    student_frame = ttk.Frame(class_list)
    student_view = Listbox(student_frame, height=10, width=30)
    class1 = Radiobutton(student_frame, text='Class 1', var=v, value=1, command=assign_class)
    class2 = Radiobutton(student_frame, text='Class 2', var=v, value=2, command=assign_class)
    add_student_label = Label(student_frame, text='Add new student Email:')
    add_student_entry = Entry(student_frame, width=30)
    add_student_button = Button(student_frame, text='Add', command=check_email)
    delete_student_button = Button(student_frame, text='Delete', command=delete_student)

    add_student_entry.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=N)
    add_student_label.grid(column=2, row=0, sticky=(N, E, W))
    add_student_button.grid(column=2, row=2)
    delete_student_button.grid(column=2, row=3)
    student_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, S, E, W))
    student_view.grid(column=3, row=0, columnspan=3, rowspan=8, sticky=(N, W, S, E))
    class1.grid(column=3, row=8)
    class2.grid(column=4, row=8)


root = Tk()
root.title("Dr. Emailio Robotus")
root.geometry('600x700-670+120')
root.minsize(400, 500)

v = IntVar()
p = IntVar()
z = IntVar()

t1 = StringVar()
t2 = StringVar()
t3 = StringVar()
t4 = StringVar()
t5 = StringVar()
t6 = StringVar()
t7 = StringVar()
t8 = StringVar()
t9 = StringVar()
t10 = StringVar()
t11 = StringVar()
t12 = StringVar()
t13 = StringVar()

# data = open('students1.txt', encoding='utf-8')
data = open(os.path.join(__location__, 'students1.txt'))
emails = data.read()
emails1 = emails.split('\n')
emails1 = Variable(value=emails1)
data.close()

data = open(os.path.join(__location__, 'students2.txt'))
emails = data.read()
emails2 = emails.split('\n')
emails2 = Variable(value=emails2)
data.close()

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="5", borderwidth=5, relief='solid')

this_lab_name = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=50, background='grey', textvariable=t1)
this_lab_name_label = Label(mainframe, text='This week\'s lab name:')

zoom_date_time = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=50, background='grey', textvariable=t2)
zoom_date_time_label = Label(mainframe, text='This week\'s Zoom meeting (date/time):')

zoom_link = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=50, background='grey', textvariable=t3)
zoom_link_label = Label(mainframe, text='This week\'s Zoom link:')

zoom_ID = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=50, background='grey', textvariable=t4)
zoom_ID_label = Label(mainframe, text='This week\'s Zoom meeting ID:')

zoom_passcode = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=50, background='grey', textvariable=t5)
zoom_passcode_label = Label(mainframe, text='This week\'s Zoom meeting passcode:')

this_lab_supplemental = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=50, background='grey', textvariable=t6)
this_lab_supplemental_label = Label(mainframe, text='This week\'s lab\'s supplemental questions:')

this_lab_consisting = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=50, background='grey', textvariable=t7)
this_lab_consisting_label = Label(mainframe, text='This week\'s lab should be consisting of:')

this_lab_due = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=50, background='grey', textvariable=t8)
this_lab_due_label = Label(mainframe, text='This week\'s lab is due (date/time):')

file_name_tag = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=50, background='grey', textvariable=t9)
file_name_tag_label = Label(mainframe, text='This week\'s lab naming format (Aspirin/Hess):')

last_lab_reminder = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=50, background='grey', textvariable=t10)
last_lab_reminder_label = Label(mainframe, text='Last week\'s lab name:')

last_lab_due = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=50, background='grey', textvariable=t11)
last_lab_due_label = Label(mainframe, text='Last week\'s lab is due (date/time):')

last_lab_supplemental = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=50, background='grey', textvariable=t12)
last_lab_supplemental_label = Label(mainframe, text='Last week\'s lab\'s supplemental questions:')

last_file_name_tag = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=50, background='grey', textvariable=t13)
last_file_name_tag_label = Label(mainframe, text='Last week\'s lab naming format (Aspirin/Hess):')

compile_button = Button(mainframe, text='Compile Email', command=format_email, width=25)
view_email_button = Button(mainframe, text='View Email', state='disabled', command=display_email, width=25)

classes_button = Button(mainframe, text='View/Modify Class List', command=class_list_view, width=18)

send_button = Button(mainframe, text='Send Email...', width=18, state='disabled', command=send_email)

mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, S, E, W))

this_lab_name.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=E, padx=3, pady=3)
this_lab_name_label.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=W, padx=3, pady=3)

zoom_date_time.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=E, padx=3, pady=3)
zoom_date_time_label.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=W, padx=3, pady=3)

zoom_link.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=E, padx=3, pady=3)
zoom_link_label.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=W, padx=3, pady=3)

zoom_ID.grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=E, padx=3, pady=3)
zoom_ID_label.grid(column=0, row=3, sticky=W, padx=3, pady=3)

zoom_passcode.grid(column=1, row=4, sticky=E, padx=3, pady=3)
zoom_passcode_label.grid(column=0, row=4, sticky=W, padx=3, pady=3)

this_lab_supplemental.grid(column=1, row=5, sticky=E, padx=3, pady=3)
this_lab_supplemental_label.grid(column=0, row=5, sticky=W, padx=3, pady=3)

this_lab_consisting.grid(column=1, row=6, sticky=E, padx=3, pady=3)
this_lab_consisting_label.grid(column=0, row=6, sticky=W, padx=3, pady=3)

this_lab_due.grid(column=1, row=7, sticky=E, padx=3, pady=3)
this_lab_due_label.grid(column=0, row=7, sticky=W, padx=3, pady=3)

file_name_tag.grid(column=1, row=8, sticky=E, padx=3, pady=3)
file_name_tag_label.grid(column=0, row=8, sticky=W, padx=3, pady=3)

last_lab_reminder.grid(column=1, row=9, sticky=E, padx=3, pady=3)
last_lab_reminder_label.grid(column=0, row=9, sticky=W, padx=3, pady=3)

last_lab_due.grid(column=1, row=10, sticky=E, padx=3, pady=3)
last_lab_due_label.grid(column=0, row=10, sticky=W, padx=3, pady=3)

last_lab_supplemental.grid(column=1, row=11, sticky=E, padx=3, pady=3)
last_lab_supplemental_label.grid(column=0, row=11, sticky=W, padx=3, pady=3)

last_file_name_tag.grid(column=1, row=12, sticky=E, padx=3, pady=3)
last_file_name_tag_label.grid(column=0, row=12, sticky=W, padx=3, pady=3)

compile_button.grid(column=0, row=13, columnspan=2, padx=3, pady=3)
view_email_button.grid(column=0, row=14, columnspan=2, padx=3, pady=3)
classes_button.grid(row=15, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=3, pady=3)
send_button.grid(row=16, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=3, pady=3)

root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
# mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
# mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
# mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
# mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is the current/working directory of your CMD window? And does your script access some files?

Comment: The script does access files and I have changed my .spec file to include them now, will update the above code. I am only able to run the .exe file from the directory housing the .py file and the data files.

Comment: I think you need to change `datas=[('students1.txt', 'students1.txt'),('students2.txt','students2.txt')]` to `datas=[('students1.txt', '.'),('students2.txt','.')]`.

Comment: @acw1668 That got it to run! I am now able to run the .exe just fine. Now the only problem I have is that it doesn't seem to be saving the changes made to the .txt file. It was saving the changes to the text file when I was running the earlier builds from the command line however.

Comment: You can't package text files into your exe that you are going to edit and expect to save the changes magically - when the exe exits all the temporary folders+files it runs from are autoamtically deleted removing your updated files - you'll have to persist them somewhere outside the exe and access them there using a specific path+filename. You could package the default contents of these files into your exe then if the persistent files don't already exist on the path you have specified then initialise the persistent files from these ones bundled into the exe?

Comment: @barny When you say 'outside the exe' do you mean they would need to be in a different directory than the .exe? I don't see why it can open the text files from a relative path and read from them, but then cannot write to them (not doubting you, just saying I don't get why)

Comment: If the files are packaged into the exe, they will be extracted into/below the temporary folder where it runs, and yes your code can happily read them there, and write them, but that’s it - any updates to these files will be lost when the program exits and the temporary folder is deleted. So if you want files that persist with a different lifetime from the exe then these files that are updated must *not* be bundled in the exe - they must persist somewhere like your home folder, or somewhere, anywhere, where they aren’t in the temporary folder the exe is extracted to and run from.

Comment: Yes they can be in the folder the .exe files is in - my point is they can’t be bundled into the exe except as maybe a starter content which your code copies to become the actual persistent files outside the exe. So if files are referenced in the .spec file these _can’t_ be updated in that location - this location will be deleted when the program exits. Referencing data files in the spec will at runtime extract those files to that relative location in the temporary folder the exe content is extracted to. ‘Temporary’ means what it says - the files will be deleted when the program exits.

Comment: @barny According to the spec file, OP is using *single directory* option, not *single executable*.

Comment: You open the txt files in read mode when you want to update them.  You should open them in write mode.

Comment: @acw1668 That was it! Feel silly overlooking that lol. Thanks for all the help yall I really appreciate it!

Comment: @acw1668 if you would 'answer' the question with the two pieces of info you gave me I could mark it as the answer! Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the advice given I was able to get the program to run. I had to change the .spec file, specifically the datas field in order to get it to work.

However I was then having a problem where the .txt files would load into the program, but upon editing them the edits were not saved as they should be. Solution: I had not put the files into 'w' mode, and this is why I wasn't getting any output to the text files. All is working now! Thank you to everyone for helping. I have updated the files above to reflect the final working version

Answer (score 1):

Try the below `spec` file. I just changed the property `console=True` to `console=False` Note that now you need to run `pyinstaller main.spec` instead of `pyinstaller main.py`.

If you don't want to use this spec file, and just want to do it from the script add `--noconsole` or `--windowed` in command when you run `pyinstaller main.py`.

eg `pyinstaller main.py --noconsole`.

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['__main__.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\wiley\\PycharmProjects\\EmailBot\\email_bot'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='__main__',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=False)
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='__main__')
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I used the spec file you provided above, and now when I run the .exe I get a little pop-window that says: "Fatal error detected: Failed to execute script __main__". The program still runs fine when I run the .exe from the CMD line though.

Comment: I wrote alternate instructions for you here https://gist.github.com/pssolanki111/f01ad4e82df4e2ad0b6f66ef935a282b .. Because SO has char limit for comments. I'll add that to my answer if that works.

Comment: I followed all the instructions and everything worked fine in the CMD. However I still get the same error when trying to run the .exe in the dist folder: "Fatal error detected: Failed to execute script main" I am only able to run the dist .exe if my CMD is in the same folder I have all my files in (the one used to make the .exe). If I try running the .exe in the build folder, I get a pop up that says "Fatal Error Detected: Error loading Python DLL ... LoadLibrary: the specified module could not be found"

Comment: @wileyrivers Now I can't explain why it doesn't work. Any chance you could provide the script and I'll see if I can create a standalone. If I'm able to, this issue might be with `pyi` install or `setuptools`.

Comment: I was able to get it working following the comment  by @acw1668 above, I am just now having a problem with the output saving

Comment: @wileyrivers Hello, I am facing the same issue here. I can open the .exe file in the terminal but when I double click on the application it throws Fatal Error: Failed to execute the script. How did you manage to solve it?